# Store both Image and Text in single column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, image, varbinary

I'm suppose to create reference table, to store key value pair.

```
Id
Key
Value
```

Thing is, i need to store both text and image as values, which kind of datatype should be better for this. most case ppl refer `Varbinary`. but i need to know which one was the best.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if just store them as separate <strike>fields</strike> columns?

```
Id bigint, Key varchar(50), ValueBlob varbinary(max),ValueString varchar(max)
```

Comment: _Columns_, not fields.

Comment: Thank You, and I'm updated this with bit column as flag to identified the text and image.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `varbinary(max)` unless you encode the image to, say, [base 64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

> Base64 is a group of similar binary-to-text encoding schemes that represent binary data in an ASCII string format

If you can't/won't, you'll need to CONVERT the text data into `varbinary(max)`

That answers your actual question, but does not solve your problem

- How will you know what type is stored in the column?
  You'll need an extra column to store "type"
- Do you intend to search/export the text stored in varbinary in the database?
  A lot of extra work

A key-value table structure suggests an EAV design which brings a lot of other problems.

Correct solutions:

- separate tables for each type of data
- separate varchar and varbinary columns